# unable to deploy tibco bw6 app in TEA, github action pipeline log its showing success but its not showing in TEA

Tags: github-actions, cicd, tibco

I am using Github Action pipeline to deploy Tibco bw6 application in dev environment, below is my github action pipeline yaml file

```
    name: Tibco Workflow

on:
  
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:
     runs-on: windows-latest
    
     steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install PSScriptAnalyzer module
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Set-PSRepository PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
          Install-Module PSScriptAnalyzer -ErrorAction Stop
      - name: Get list of rules
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule


      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
         java-version: 11.0.16+8
         distribution: 'adopt'
         cache: maven

          
      - name: Build BW6 Application
        run: mvn clean install -f src/sm.jdbcHana/pom.xml


  deployment: 
     needs: build   
     runs-on: windows-latest
     steps:      
       - name: Deploy to TIBCO Enterprise Administrator
         uses: tibcosoftware/tibco-action-deploy@v1.1.0
         with:
            tibco_home: http://url
            tibco_domain: BW6_Migrated
            tibco_admin: usedid
            tibco_password: password
            app_file: ./target/my_app.ear
            appname: "jdbchana"
            appversion: "1.0"
```

as per github action log deployment showing success but in TEA the app not showing, below is the log of deployment stage

Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'tibco_home', 'tibco_domain', 'tibco_admin', 'tibco_password', 'app_file', 'appname', 'appversion', valid inputs are ['repository', 'ref', 'token', 'ssh-key', 'ssh-known-hosts', 'ssh-strict', 'persist-credentials', 'path', 'clean', 'fetch-depth', 'lfs', 'submodules', 'set-safe-directory', 'github-server-url']
Run actions/checkout@v3
Syncing repository: ogeenergycorp/sm.jdbcHana
Getting Git version info
Temporarily overriding HOME='D:\a_temp\754e3a0f-c66c-41a1-84ca-cdfbe530575a' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config --global --add safe.directory D:\a\sm.jdbcHana\sm.jdbcHana
Deleting the contents of 'D:\a\sm.jdbcHana\sm.jdbcHana'
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" log -1 --format='%H'
'0a1f136f2e0cee77954951ff3daf6636dc3217b7'

Comment: Jobs are run into different runners. The artifact built under `build` job is not visible to `deployment` job. Either perform it under one single job; or, upload from `build` as an artifact and download under `deployment` job to deploy. Apart from that, `tibcosoftware/tibco-action-deploy` doesn't seem to have all those configured inputs. And, I just checked this https://github.com/tibcosoftware/tibco-action-deploy and got a 404. Not sure how you're using it though.

Comment: This seems relevant: [TCLI: Setting up GitHub Actions with TCLI](https://tibcosoftware.github.io/TCSToolkit/cli/tutorials/007_Github_Actions/)